# Posicionamento de um thumbnail

Tags: css, wordpress

Tenho um site(usando o Wordpress) com várias thumbnails, estas thumbs estão centradas na vertical e horizontal como mostra a imagem: [image: thumbs]

Como fazer para que as thumbs mostrem o topo da imagem e cortem a parte inferior se ela não couber?

```css
/*.recent-posts .post-thumb {
margin: 0;
position: relative;
}*/
.recent-posts .post-thumb {
margin: 0;
position: relative;
height: 180px;
overflow: hidden !important;
vertical-align: top; /* talvez esse não se faça necessário */
}

.recent-posts .post-thumb img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.recent-posts .post-thumb img:hover {
opacity: .7;
transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.recent-posts .post-thumb img {
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.recent-posts .post-content {
padding: 10px 15px;
background-color: #1f1f1f;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
-moz-border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

.recent-posts li:hover .post-content {
background-color: #252525;
}

.recent-posts li:hover .video-icon {
opacity: .9;
}

.recent-posts h2 {
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 1.3;
margin: 0 0 5px;
}

.recent-posts h2 a {
color: #fff;
}

.recent-posts h2 a:hover {
color: #ccc;
}


/* Posts in Blog template */

.archive-blog .recent-posts li {
margin: 0 0 30px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

.archive-blog .recent-posts li:before,
.archive-blog .recent-posts li:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.archive-blog .recent-posts li:after { clear: both; }

.archive-blog .recent-posts li .post-thumb {
float: left;
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.archive-blog .recent-posts .post-thumb img {
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}


.archive-blog .recent-posts li .post-content {
background: none;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

 <?php if ( option::is_on( 'display_thumb' ) ) { ?>

  <div class="post-thumb">

   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

    <?php if ( has_post_format( 'video' ) ) {
     echo '<span class="video-icon"></span>';
     }
    ?>
    
    
    <?php 
     get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'loop', 'link_to_post' => false, 'width' => 260, 'height' => 180 ) );  
     //get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'loop', 'link_to_post' => false ) );  
     //get_the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); 
    ?>


   </a>

  </div>

 <?php } ?>

 <div class="post-content">

  <div class="post-meta">

   <?php if ( option::is_on( 'display_category' ) ) { ?>
    <span class="meta-category"><?php the_category(' / '); ?></span>
   <?php } ?>

   </div>

  <h2 class="truncate"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

  <div class="post-meta">

   <?php if ( option::is_on( 'display_date' ) ) { ?>
    <span class="meta-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
   <?php } ?>

    <?php edit_post_link( __('Edit', 'wpzoom'), '<span>', '</span>'); ?>

  </div>

  <?php if ( option::is_on( 'display_excerpt' ) ) {

   the_excerpt(); }

   if(get_field('streaming1') || get_field('streaming2') || get_field('streaming3') || get_field('download720') || get_field('download1080')) {
    if(get_field('download720')) {
     echo '<a href="' . get_field('download720') . '" class="wpz-sc-button teal small" style="padding: 5px 10px"><span class="wpz-download">720p</span></a>';
    }

    if(get_field('download1080')) {
     echo '<a href="' . get_field('download1080') . '" class="wpz-sc-button small" style="padding: 5px 10px"><span class="wpz-download">1080p</span></a>';
    }
   } else {
    echo '<a href="#" class="wpz-sc-button red small" style="padding: 5px 10px"><span class="wpz-info">Em breve</span></a>';
   }
  ?>


  <?php if ( option::is_on( 'display_readmore' ) ) { ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="more-link" rel="nofollow"><?php _e('Read more', 'wpzoom'); ?> &raquo;</a>
  <?php } ?>

  <div class="clear"></div>

 </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Pode postar o HTML e CSS correspondente ?

Comment: Com certeza, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente:

```
<style type="text/css">
.recent-posts .post-thumb {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    vertical-align: top; /* talvez esse não se faça necessário */
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hummmm, ainda não... Alterei o CSS, a parte comentada é como estava antes. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver seu problema assim:

```
.post-thumb > a{
    display: block!important;
    height: 180px!important; /*Aqui seria a altura máxima que você quer*/
    overflow: hidden!important;
    position: relative!important;
}
```

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, não sei porque... A folha de estilo completa: http://ultratorrent.com.br/wp-content/themes/videozoom/style.css

Comment: Desculpa a pergunta boba, talvez seria melhor fazer isso em outra pergunta, mas qual a diferença entre .post-thumb a, .post-thumb > a e a.post-thumb?

Comment: Estou testando pelo debugador e está funcionando ok. Você verificou se colocou depois do seu estilo principal ?

Comment: Básicamente estou dizendo que somente os filhos '*a*' direto de *.post-thumb* devem ter o tal estilo.

Comment: http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/guia-completo-seletores-css3.php

Comment: Bem lembrado, havia colocado acima dos outros estilos, agora coloquei nas últimas linhas do style.css, mesmo assim, ainda sem sucesso...

Comment: Obrigado pelo link do tutorial, eu vou ler.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43315/discussion-between-ricardo-mota-and-sistematico).

Comment: Tente adicionar os *important* igual na edição da resposta

Comment: Pode passar o link exato da página que esta tentando ?

Comment: http://ultratorrent.com.br

Comment: como Você esta fazendo os testes. Pelo que pude ver as imagens são todas do mesmo tamanho, para ver se funciona você teria que diminuir um pouco. Ou colocar uma imagem maior agora pra testarmos.

Comment: Acho que você matou a charada, o Wordpress está cortando a imagem, não o CSS, exemplo de um Thumb: http://ultratorrent.com.br/wp-content/uploads/gladiator-260x180.jpg , agora a dúvida, como mudar isso?

Comment: get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'loop', 'link_to_post' => false, 'width' => 260, 'height' => 180 ) ); agora porque ele corta desse jeito, eu não sei...

Comment: Está usando algum plugin de upload certo ? Acredito que a documentação do mesmo deve mencionar algo sobre.

Comment: Acertou na mosca...

Answer (score 0):

Alterada a função:

```
get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'loop', 'link_to_post' => false, 'width' => 260, 'height' => 180 ) );
```

Por:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id );
```

Desculpem a desinformação...